# I want a mock function written in Typescript and Jest for Logger.log method of Google Apps Script

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, ts-jest, clasp

I want to test a Google Apps Script code written in TypeScript using Jest on my local laptop. The code has a method call, `Logger.log`, which is specific to GAS, and I have to give the tester a mock function for.

Code to be tested `./src/code.ts`:

```js
export function hello(name: string): string {
  return `hello ${name}`;
}

function main(): void {
  Logger.log(hello('yamada'));
}

main();
```

Testing code `./__tests__/code.spec.ts`:

```js
import {hello} from '../src/code';

class Logger {
    static log(msg: string): void {
        console.log(msg);
    };
}

describe('test for hello function', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
    });

    it('adds "hello" before the argument and returns them', () => {
        const result = hello('john');
        expect(result).toBe('hello john');
    });
});
```

I expected the test to run and succeed when I executed `npx jest`, but I got:

```
FAIL __tests__/code.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Logger is not defined

      4 |
      5 | function main(): void {
    > 6 |   Logger.log(hello('yamada'));
        |   ^
      7 | }
      8 |
      9 | main();

      at main (src/code.ts:6:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/code.ts:9:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/code.spec.ts:1:1)
```

When I transpiled `./src/code.ts` using `npx tsc`, it succeeded.
After removing the emitted file, `./src/code.js`, I ran `npx jest` again, then the same message came out.

The tester seemed to find the definition of `hello` function in the remote file, but not to find `Logger` class in the same file. That looks strange and curious.

What should I do for both the mock class, `Logger`, and its method, `log` to work.

Environment:

| command | version |
| --- | --- |
| node | 16.13.0 |
| clasp | 2.4.1 |
| tsc | 4.4.4 |
| jest | 27.3.1 |

`./package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "sample2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "tsc src/code.ts",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google/clasp": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/google-apps-script": "^1.0.39",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.2"
  }
}
```

`./jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    },
    globals: {
    },
};
```

I tried:

- Set `globals` and keep class `Logger`

  `./jest.config.js`

  ```js
  module.exports = {
      ... ,
      globals: {
          Logger: {}
      },
  };
  ```

  The result is below:

  ```
  TypeError: Logger.log is not a function
  ```

  The `Logger` was defined, and my definition of `Logger.log` didn't work.
- Set `globals` and define `Logger.log`:

  `./__tests__/code.spec.ts`

  ```js
  import {hello} from '../src/code';

  describe('test for hello function', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
          Logger.log = jest.fn(msg => {
              console.log(msg);
          });
      });
  ...
  });
  ```

  That resulted the `TypeError`.
- Unset `globals` and keep class `Logger`:

  ```
  ReferenceError: Logger is not defined
  ```
- Unset `globals` and define `Logger.log`:

  That results the `ReferenceError`.
- Set `globals`, keep class and set spy:

  `./__tests__/code.spec.ts`

  ```js
      beforeAll(() => {
          ... ,
          jest.spyOn(Logger, 'log');
      });
  ```

  That caused the `TypeError`.
- Set `globals`,  define `Logger.log` and set spy:

  That happened `TypeError`.
- Unset `globals`, keep class and set spy:

  That results `ReferenceError`.
- Unset `globals`, define `Logger.log` and set spy:

  That causes `ReferenceError`.

The next table sums up these results:

| `globals` | mock type | spy | error type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| set | class Logger | X | TypeError |
| set | Logger.log | X | TypeError |
| unset | class Logger | X | ReferenceError |
| unset | Logger.log | X | ReferenceError |
| set | class Logger | O | TypeError |
| set | Logger.log | O | TypeError |
| unset | class Logger | O | ReferenceError |
| unset | Logger.log | O | ReferenceError |

Comment: `Logger: {}` <- `Logger.log` is indeed not a function, because it's undefined. Why not e.g. `Logger: { log: () => {} }`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @jonrsharpe. I passed the test.

Does the `globals` key **declare** `Logger.log()` in jest.config.js file?
Is the `Logger` class **defined** in code.spec.ts file?
Did the compiler say that the type at the definition was differnt from the one at the declaration?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, would you post your comment as an answer? Then I will close the question.